# How can I be sure if nobody changed master branch while I'm working on other branch? (Git)

Tags: git, git-branch

guys!

I made a new branch and worked in there for a while. That time my coworker changed some code in the master BUT the problem is a lot of code was changed and now we can't merge all these stuff into the master cause my code doesn't fit the new changes in master.

How should we deal with these kind of situations? Should we better discuss our zones of responsibilities and design out interfaces more independently?

Cause sometimes I rely on a code base in a master branch but also sometimes classes of functions change there, so code I write doesn't work anymore (for example, some method in a master code was removed but I used it into my branch).

Don't let my head explode, give me your feedback please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The perpetual race condition, and rebase

It's not a "situation". Having the main branch change while you are working on a side branch is *normal*.

To put it another way: you are *always* in a race condition with the usage of the main branch. That is part of life. It's *normal*. Do not try to avoid it.

You can lessen the apparent impact of this constant race condition by rebasing your branch onto the main branch just before merging or pull request or whatever you are doing. But note this largely just moves the impact to a different location; it makes for a nicer tree and a better chance of no conflict during the merge itself.

#### Merge conflicts

> and now we can't merge all these stuff into the master cause my code doesn't fit the new changes in master

Okay, that part is just wrong. Of *course* you can merge into `master`. You just can't merge into `master` *automatically.* There are conflicts and you have to resolve them. Okay, resolve them! It's not rocket science.

Again: merge conflicts are *normal*. You need to accept them and learn to deal with them.

The real issue here is the *name*. A merge is the creation of a commit. What you are doing is asking git to create the commit automatically because you are too lazy or too human / fallible to do it yourself. Git will do so, but sometimes it will say, "I can't do this part automatically, you'll have to help me by doing it manually." So you do, and there's the commit, all done. If we *called* this something like "automatic / manual commit creation" instead using words like merge and conflict, we wouldn't get so tied up in knots about it.

And this relates to what I said in part one of my answer. If there are conflicts, they will emerge during the rebase just as surely as they would have emerged during the merge later. And you will resolve them. It's not a big deal, and it's good because you've moved the onus of dealing with the conflicts onto your own machine, so that the conflict *won't* occur (or probably won't) at merge time.

#### Rebase early and often

> Cause sometimes I rely on a code base in a master branch but also sometimes classes of functions change there, so code I write doesn't work anymore (for example, some method in a master code was removed but I used it into my branch).

The way to deal with that is to do what I said in the first part, *often*. Every hour or two, commit what you're doing on the branch, switch to the main branch, and pull. Now switch back to the branch and rebase it onto the main branch. Now you have acquired whatever is new in the main branch, as part of *your* branch. If your code no longer works, you will know instantly and you can update it.